# Trying add class to element HTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add classes to different `div`, but I don't know why it doesn't work when I had created the class in the `. sass` file, and after that add using `className`, `setAttribute` or `classList`. But, when I do it in the same `.ts` file, works perfectly.

#### work

```
const tamano = 75;
const customMarker: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
customMarker.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.greenShip})`;
customMarker.style.width = `${ tamano }px`
customMarker.style.height = `${ tamano }px`
customMarker.style.backgroundSize = '100%';
customMarker.style.cursor = 'pointer'
```

#### Doesn't work

```
const customMarker: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
customMarker.setAttribute('id', 'id_ship-on-time');
customMarker.setAttribute('class', 'ship-on-time');
console.log(customMarker.outerHTML);
customMarker.className = "ship-on-time";
```

#### class

```
.ship-on-time
  background-image: url('../../../../../assets/icons/ship_green@3x.png')
  background-size: contain
  width: 70px
  height: 70px
  cursor: pointer
  background-repeat: no-repeat
```

The result in the console is that

[image: console result]

Comment: can u provide a code demo for your problem ?

Comment: Sorry it's simple, the div with the image as a background doesn't render in the DOM

Comment: see that should be:`background-image: url('/assets/icons/ship_green@3x.png');`, furthermore you need end with `;` all the properties of the class

Comment: @EliseoBut if I will put semicolon or bracket in the `.sass` file, automatically jump to me with errors

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your CSS class has the proper syntax:

```css
.ship-on-time {
  background-image: url('../../../../../assets/icons/ship_green@3x.png');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It's a `.sass` file, doesn't need semicolon and the brackets neither

Answer (score 0):

First, write your class in your `.sass` file

```css
.ship-on-time {
  background-image: url('../../../../../assets/icons/ship_green@3x.png');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

then, if you want to add this class using the DOM, you need to use `classList`

```js
customMarker.classList.add("ship-on-time");
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I had tried using this way before.